Problema con variable javascritpt en PHP
Hola tengo un curioso problema con una variable de javascript que lee valores de una base de datos y que es pasada a PHP mediante GET. Los datos que son guardados en la base de datos recogen números separados por el carácter "+". Pero cuando los vuelvo a leer para editarlos y los envío a PHP aparecen sin ese "+".
Mi función javascript es la siguiente:
function FormatearDatos(response) {
        response.forEach(elemento => {
            // Formatear el número de filtrado
            const IdFormateado = Number(elemento.id).toLocaleString('es-ES');            
            const Valores = elemento.Valores;            

           tbody.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${IdFormateado}</td>
                    <td>${Valores}</td>                    
                    <td> <a href="actions/delete.php?id=${elemento.id}" onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de que deseas borrar este registro?');">
                    <img src="../Images/basura_rojo_icon.png" alt="Borrar"></a>                                    

                    <a href="frmeditar.php?id=${elemento.id}&                                           
                    Valores=${elemento.Valores}&                    

                    <img src="../Images/editar_azul_icon.png" alt="Editar"></a>
                    </td> 
                    </tr>`;                                
        });
    }

Y la variable que recoge esos elementos en PHP es como sigue,
$Valores = $_GET['Valores'];   

Lo que no entiendo es por qué llega esa variable sin los "+". A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

El + en las URL se interpreta como un espacio. Por eso cuando Valores se envía con un +, PHP lo interpreta y lo decodifica automáticamente como un espacio en blanco.
Para solucionar este problema puedes cambiar el + por otra cosa, o puedes intentar lo siguiente.
Usa encodeURIComponent para codificar los valores que contienen caracteres especiales como el +. Esto evitará que se interpreten de manera incorrecta al pasar los datos por la URL. Ejemplo:
const Valores = encodeURIComponent(elemento.Valores);

Y para asegurarte que PHP lo pueda decodificar más tarde, puedes hacer:
$Valores = urldecode($_GET['Valores']);

Luego imprime la variable de alguna forma, para que estes seguro que el proceso se ha realizado correctamente.

Tip no relacionado:
Usa camelCase o snake_case para tus variables. La variable debería ser:

$id
$idFormateado
$id_formateado

Pero trata de no acostumbrarte a usar una mayúscula inicial, como lo haces con $Valores
